# Python ExcelWriter adding conditional formatting to multiple tables/dataframes

Tags: python, excel, conditional-formatting, pandas.excelwriter

I try to add conditional formatting to more than one table in excel.
For one table this line works

```js
worksheet.conditional_format('B3:K9', {'type':'2_color_scale', 'min_color':'yellow', 'max_color':'green'})
```

But I want to add conditional formatting also to the tables in the specified range:  M3:O9, P3:X9, B11:K17, M11:O17

I tried to pass the ranges in a list but i get the following error:

```js
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with a workaround with a loop.

```js
for i in range(0,9):
    for j in range(0,8):
        worksheet.conditional_format(2+i*10,1+j*6,8+i*10,4+j*6, {'type':'2_color_scale', 'min_color':'green', 'max_color':'yellow'})
```

The ranges changed a bit. So I start at row 3 and column 2 and color the following 7 rows and 4 columns. Then i skip the empty rows and columns.